# 'LEA reg, mem' equivalent?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Is there a x86 instruction or set of instructions, equivalent of the instruction:

```
lea rax, [rsp + 0x20]
```

I have tried the following set of instructions that I thought would be the equivalent:

```
push rbx
lea rbx, [rsp + 0x20]
mov rax, rbx
pop rbx
```

However, the alternate set of instructions causes an access violation. So the question is, is there a working equivalent of the instruction `lea reg, mem`?

Comment: `pushf` `mov rax, rsp` `add rax, 0x20` `popf` . I assume the exercise is to do it without using an LEA instruction ad all. The `pushf` and `popf` are to save and restore the flags. LEA doesn't alter the flags but ADD does.

Comment: In the general case, if `[mem]` uses a RIP-relative addressing mode, it's hard to replace.  `call next_insn` / `next_insn: pop rax` can substitute.  This difficulty is *why* x86-64 introduced the RIP-relative addressing mode.

Comment: Why can't you use the instruction itself?  It'd help to know what your constraints actually are.  Note the problem with your proposed equivalent is that `push rbx` subtracts 8 from the stack pointer, so the result you get in `rax` is off by 8.  You could do `push rbx ; lea rbx, [rsp + 0x28]; mov rax, rbx ; pop rbx` and that should be equivalent other than the effect on flags.